# Does Apache's mod_cache, used with mod_deflate cache the gziped file or cache the source?

Tags: apache-2.2

does Apache (Http-Webserver), when used with mod_cache and mod_deflate, cache the uncompressed source file and (and the compress it for every request) or does it directly save the compressed result in the cache and is therefore able to safe a lot of CPU-Resources as the file is only compressed once, when inserting it into the cache?

Thank your very much!!
Jan

Comment: And additional - is this combination usually beneficial for overall performance? i.e. Is the overhead of having many variations of gzipped resources on disk less than the cost of gzipping on every request of resources?

Answer (score 3):

The cache filter saves the response after it's been compressed with mod_deflate.

Unfortunately with the default config using mod_disk_cache, you may find one cached resource per user-agent due to the Vary headers suggested by the manual.